# Python PuLP "Overwriting Previously Set Objective" Warning When Solving Optimization Multiple Times

Tags: python, warnings, pulp

I'm working on a problem that requires me to solve the same optimization multiple times, although with a different set of variables every time. I'm using a for loop to iterate through the optimization, and for some reason, it only works the first time (the correct outcome is produced; I checked by hand). However, every time after the first time, the optimization provides a suboptimal problem. I get this statement:  warnings.warn("Overwriting previously set objective.")

By inspection, the solution that is calculated is incorrect (I'm trying to minimize the distance between pairs of objects, and it's just clearly wrong). Furthermore, the objective function is 0, which doesn't make sense, because I defined the objective to be the summed distances of pairs, so the value of the objective function should always be greater than 0. The code is pretty long, but maybe it'll show what I'm doing wrong. This is what I'm iterating over:

```
model = pulp.LpProblem('R_lessthan_V_' + str(t), LpMinimize)        

    #Set variables to optimize
    x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('single_ride_' + str(t), ((i.num, j.num) for i in R_prime for j in V_prime), cat = 'Binary')
    x_prime = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('shared_ride_' + str(t), ((i.num, j.num) for i in R_prime for j in V_prime), cat = 'Binary')

    #Set objective function
    model += (pulp.lpSum([pulp.lpSum([[x[(i.num, j.num)] * (d[i.num][j.num] + phi * p[j.num])]
    + [x_prime[(i.num, j.num)] * rideshare_pen[i.num][j.num][0]]
    + [delta * q[j.num] * (x[(i.num, j.num)] + x_prime[(i.num, j.num)]) * (1 - y[i.num][j.num])]
    for i in R_prime]) for j in V_prime])), 'wait_cost_' + str(t)

    #Set constraints
    for j in V_prime:
        label = 'rideshare_pass_constraint_time%d_v%d' % (t, j.num)
        condition = p[j.num] >= pulp.lpSum([[x_prime[(i.num, j.num)]] for i in R_prime]) #passenger 1 before 2 ride-share
        model += condition, label

        label_single = 'one_max_single_time%d_v%d' % (t, j.num)
        label_shared = 'one_max_shared_time%d_v%d' % (t, j.num)
        condition_single = pulp.lpSum([[x[(i.num, j.num)]] for i in R_prime]) <= 1 #cap the number of single rides for each vehicle
        condition_shared = pulp.lpSum([[x_prime[(i.num, j.num)]] for i in R_prime]) <= 1 #cap the number of ride shares for each vehicle
        model += condition_single, label_single
        model += condition_shared, label_shared

    for i in R_prime:
        label = 'all_assigned_time%d_p%d' % (t, i.num)
        condition = pulp.lpSum([[x[(i.num, j.num)]] + [x_prime[(i.num, j.num)]] for j in V_prime]) == 1 #every passenger is assigned
        model += condition, label

    for i in R_prime:
        for j in V_prime:
            label_single = 'nonneg_single_time%d_p%d_i%d' % (t, i.num, j.num)
            label_shared = 'nonneg_shared_time%d_p%d_i%d' % (t, i.num, j.num)
            condition_single = x[(i.num, j.num)] >= 0 #nonnegative single rides
            condition_shared = x_prime[(i.num, j.num)] >= 0 #nonnegative ride shares
            model += condition_single, label_single
            model += condition_shared, label_shared

    for i in R_A:
        label = 'stay_assigned_time%d_p%d' % (t, i.num)
        condition = pulp.lpSum([x[(i.num, j.num)]] + [x_prime[(i.num, j.num)]]) #prevents assigned -> unassigned
        model += condition, label

        for j in V_P:
            label_single = 'reassign_single_time%d_p%d_i%d' % (t, i.num, j.num)
            label_shared = 'reassign_shared_time%d_p%d_i%d' % (t, i.num, j.num)
            condition_single = b[i.num] * (y[i.num][j.num] - x[(i.num,j.num)]) <= 0  #prevents more than 1 reassignment
            condition_shared = b[i.num] * (y[i.num][j.num] - x_prime[(i.num,j.num)]) <= 0  #prevents more than 1 reassignment
            model += condition_single, label_single
            model += condition_shared, label_shared
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

where is the iteration? I only see one model and it is not solved in that code

also

```
model += pulp.lpSum(x[(i.num, j.num)] * (d[i.num][j.num] + phi * p[j.num])
+ x_prime[(i.num, j.num)] * rideshare_pen[i.num][j.num][0]
+ delta * q[j.num] * (x[(i.num, j.num)] + x_prime[(i.num, j.num)]) * (1 - y[i.num][j.num])
for i in R_prime for j in V_prime), 'wait_cost_' + str(t)
```

is more idiomatic

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response; essentially this code is part of a function (that is called many times). I call model.solve() shortly after, but I didn't include those parts since I didn't think it was as relevant as the definition of the model itself, but would it help if I included everything? I will make that idiomatic change.